# Compile failed when compiling ros_control

Tags: debian, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had ROS (indigo) running on a BeagleBone Black (running debian), by compiling everything, following this link:

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian

I then tried to compile in ros_control (following all the steps at the bottom of the page)

```
rosinstall_generator ros_comm ros_control --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-custom_ros.rosinstall
```

The compile failed when trying to compile joint_limit_interface:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'joint_limits_interface'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros_control/joint_limits_interface -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/joint_limits_interface -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/debian/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/joint_limits_interface'
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findurdfdom.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "urdfdom", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "urdfdom" with any
  of the following names:

    urdfdomConfig.cmake
    urdfdom-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "urdfdom" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "urdfdom_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "urdfdom" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Looking around, there seems to be some talk on this, but I am still confused on how to proceed with the build.

Anyone have any step by step instructions on how to proceed?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220772/compile-failed-when-compiling-ros_control/) by [MarkG](https://answers.ros.org/users/20930/markg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To add to the answer by @tfoote: you need to make sure you have installed all dependencies *before* trying to build packages from source.

In most cases a `rosdep check --from-paths /path/to/your/workspace/src --ignore-src --rosdistro=$DISTRO` should tell you whether anything is missing. You can then either install the missing dependencies by hand, or run `rosdep install ..` with the same arguments to have `rosdep` install everything for you.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarkG](https://answers.ros.org/users/20930/markg/) on 2015-11-12**:
I appreciate everyones feedback.  I should have re-read the original link on installing on Debian.  I did do a rosdep check...  but missed the part about urdfdom(I reran it to verify)...  Since this is Debian Wheezy on a BeagleBone, I need to compile a lot of system files including urdfdom, along with all ROS packages...  Sometimes my eyes get crossed :)

By following the compile instructions for liburdfdom, I was able to successfully compile the rs_control package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install liburdfdom-dev it is a system dependency: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/liburdfdom-dev

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1